# How to modify vector in a BAS model function (R)

Tags: r, vector, lm

I'm trying to run a bas.lm model and I want to specify a null model, but I don't understand one bit of the code

I've built almost the entire model, but I want the first one to be the one with only predictors 1, 2, 3 and the second one to be with all 3 + new predictor. For this, I think the "bestmodel" argument is used, but I don't understand how it works. The documentation says it's: "optional binary vector representing a model to initialize the sampling. If NULL sampling starts with the null model" and the source code for the null is

```
bestmodel <- c(1, rep(0, p - 1))
```

But I have no idea how to change it to refer to my variables

This is the model currently with data and results:

```
Mean_Accuracy Predictor1 Predictor2 Predictor3   NewPredictor
0.73             3          7           6             8
0.50             4          5           1             5
0.86             1          3           4             1

Accuracy <- bas.lm(Mean_Accuracy ~ .,
                     data = df,
                     method = "BAS",
                     bestmodel = NULL,
                     prior = "JZS",
                     include.always = Mean_Accuracy ~ Predictor1 + Predictor2 + Predictor3, 
                     #bestmodel = c(?,?),
                     modelprior = uniform())

summary(Accuracy)
           P(B != 0 | Y)   model 1       model 2
Intercept              1    1.0000  1.000000e+00
NewPredictor           1    1.0000  0.000000e+00
Predictor1             1    1.0000  1.000000e+00
Predictor2             1    1.0000  1.000000e+00
Predictor3             1    1.0000  1.000000e+00
BF                    NA    1.0000 4.642017e-139
PostProbs             NA    1.0000  0.000000e+00
R2                    NA    0.3506  2.710000e-01
dim                   NA    7.0000  6.000000e+00
logmarg               NA 1179.9872  8.614630e+02
```

All I want is for the 2nd model to come first as the null with BF=1. Is there a way to modify the code accordingly?